# VLC Plugin trouble

Tags: html, css, plugins

I am trying to 'theme' and position the pluging via css.
Here a piece of code:

```
<!-- vlc-player -->
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
width="660"
height="420"
id="vlc"
autoplay="yes"
allowfullscreen="yes"
windowless="yes"
mute="no"
loop="no"
toolbar="no"
bgcolor="#111111"
text="pirate-radio.eu"
branding="false"
target="lollipop.mp4">
</embed>
<!-- vlc-player end -->
```

Nothing fancy...

With this 'configuration' the player runs fine in FF and has a black background.
(Why, supposed to be #111?)
CSS attributes like 'opacity', 'z-index' and positioning via the "vlc"-id (I use in CSS as well) does what it should do.
However, in Chrome it shows a little bit different results.
First, the background of the player comes transparent, not black.
Second, the position of the player is shifted about 2-3px to the right (where I can life with but it be nice to know why too...)

If I evite CSS-rules both player-backgrounds come black.

Question is, is it the right way to use the forementioned id ("vlc") in CSS for reference?
If I wrap the embed-tag into a box (div) it isn't possible to target the player anymore.
How an I target the player properly to 'ccs it'?

Answer (score 0):

I just messed up with another player I tested before and hadn't given me the results expected.

The correct implementation of a VLC-Player is (like published on several sites) for example as follows:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
width="660"
height="370"
id="vlc"
autoplay="true"
allowfullscreen="false"
windowless="true"
mute="false"
loop="true"
toolbar="false"
bgcolor="#111111"
text=""
branding="false"
controls="false"
target="media/video/TESTCARD.mp4">
</embed>
```

So far so good?

Greets

Gee